# React.js component to lazy-load image

Tags: image, react.js, jsx, lazy

I'm trying to design a better solution for img srcset with lazy load.
Below is the code from the component responsible for lazy load img, 
maybe someone has a better way to achieve this effect.

Full [github repo](https://github.com/JacobJSLove/messenger-ssr/tree/389b3e5e135cdda33282efdf0df45a298a273991)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const ImageLoader = ({ alt, height, id, width }) => {

  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const ImageWrapper = useRef(null);

  const mobile = `data/${id}_m.jpg`;
  const tablet = `data/${id}_t.jpg`;
  const src = `data/${id}.jpg`;
  useEffect(() => {
    const img = new Image(width, height);
    img.onload = () => setLoaded(true);
    img.src = src;
    img.sizes = "(max-width: 1500px) 33vw, 40vw";
    img.srcset = `${mobile} 1000w, ${tablet} 1300w, ${src} 2000w`;
    img.alt = alt;
    ImageWrapper.current.appendChild(img);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: `${width}px`,height:`${height}px` }} className="ImageWrapper" ref={ImageWrapper}>
      {!loaded ? (
        <svg x="0px" y="0px" width={width} height={height} viewBox="0 0 53 53">
                <path style={{fill: '#E7ECED'}}  d="M18.613,41.552l-7.907,4.313c-0.464,0.253-0.881,0.564-1.269,0.903C14.047,50.655,19.998,53,26.5,53
                c6.454,0,12.367-2.31,16.964-6.144c-0.424-0.358-0.884-0.68-1.394-0.934l-8.467-4.233c-1.094-0.547-1.785-1.665-1.785-2.888v-3.322
                c0.238-0.271,0.51-0.619,0.801-1.03c1.154-1.63,2.027-3.423,2.632-5.304c1.086-0.335,1.886-1.338,1.886-2.53v-3.546
                c0-0.78-0.347-1.477-0.886-1.965v-5.126c0,0,1.053-7.977-9.75-7.977s-9.75,7.977-9.75,7.977v5.126
                c-0.54,0.488-0.886,1.185-0.886,1.965v3.546c0,0.934,0.491,1.756,1.226,2.231c0.886,3.857,3.206,6.633,3.206,6.633v3.24
                C20.296,39.899,19.65,40.986,18.613,41.552z" />
                <g>
                  <path style={{fill: '#556080'}} d="M26.953,0.004C12.32-0.246,0.254,11.414,0.004,26.047C-0.138,34.344,3.56,41.801,9.448,46.76
                c0.385-0.336,0.798-0.644,1.257-0.894l7.907-4.313c1.037-0.566,1.683-1.653,1.683-2.835v-3.24c0,0-2.321-2.776-3.206-6.633
                c-0.734-0.475-1.226-1.296-1.226-2.231v-3.546c0-0.78,0.347-1.477,0.886-1.965v-5.126c0,0-1.053-7.977,9.75-7.977
                s9.75,7.977,9.75,7.977v5.126c0.54,0.488,0.886,1.185,0.886,1.965v3.546c0,1.192-0.8,2.195-1.886,2.53
                c-0.605,1.881-1.478,3.674-2.632,5.304c-0.291,0.411-0.563,0.759-0.801,1.03V38.8c0,1.223,0.691,2.342,1.785,2.888l8.467,4.233
                c0.508,0.254,0.967,0.575,1.39,0.932c5.71-4.762,9.399-11.882,9.536-19.9C53.246,12.32,41.587,0.254,26.953,0.004z" />
              </g>
          </svg>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
};


export default ImageLoader;
```

Comment: The word `trying` sometimes indicates the code is not working as expected, which would make the question off-topic for code review. If you are having performance issues and are and looking for suggestions on how to improve the performance, please add the `performance` tag.